# i have multiple videos in a page i need to pause video when i play another video in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, video, ionic-framework

I have multiple videos in a page. I want to pause all other videos when I play a video in ionic framework.

I am using not only you tube videos but also from other sources.

part of my html page

```
<ion-list>
        <div class="card">
            <ion-item ng-repeat="module in co.Modules">
                  {{module.name}}
 <div class="video-container">

                   <iframe allowscriptaccess="always" ng-src="{{module.link}}" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen></iframe>

                </div>
            </ion-item>
        </div>

<div class="col text-center">
<button class="button button-large button-positive" ng-click="vm.onclick(co.course_name)" >
   Take Assesment
</button>
</div>

</ion-list>
```

Comment: Check this link for help http://jsfiddle.net/Lz3vkwmw/1/

Comment: please give me some code using iframe tag.@Anuj Gupta

Comment: please give me some code using iframe tag@Anuj

Answer (score 0):

for this please use iframe in ionic my code is bellow.

HTML

```
 <div class="video-container">
    <iframe ng-src="{{getIframeSrc(videoNewsData.VIDEOSCRIPT)}}" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.getIframeSrc = function(videoId) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId);
};
```

Comment: please give me some other answer deal with iframe

Comment: I am using not only you tube videos but also other sources. Is this code work for other sources@kaushal